# Connecting a current follower to a Raspberry Pi with an MCP3008

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi

One of the experiments I conduct in an instrumental methods class is the construction of a rudimentary spectrophotometer described in the *Journal of Chemical Education* (link [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ed078p1510) if you have access to this journal).  The schematic of the instrument from the paper is:

[image]

and we make a few minor changes (fixed resistance for the LED, +/- 9V sources and LM301 op amp).  I'd like to expand this project so that the data is read using a Raspberry Pi rather than a multimeter.  I've had success using [these instructions](http://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi/connecting-the-cobbler-to-a-mcp3008) to use an MCP3008 to read an analog signal with the RPi.  I'd like to combine these two projects; however, I recognize that the instrument outputs 0 to -9V which the RPi can't handle.  I've more-or-less reached the limit of my electronics knowledge at this point and would welcome suggestions on how to move forward with this project (including RTFM answers, if you care to tell me which manual to stick my nose in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what "OED" is but if it's a photodiode you could reverse its bias to -15V and reverse the diode in the circuit. When light hits the diode it will cause current flow out of the op-amp's virtual earth and the op-amp output will rise positively.

You still need to create a negative supply for the photodiode but this will be very low power. Regarding the output level created by the circuit, if your RaPi limit is (say) 3V3 then you can use a resistor potential divider for lowering the output or just run the op-amp from 0V and +3V3 (or whatever power source is available).

Comment: The "OED" is one of several optical-electronic-devices, which in my case is a simple photoresistor.  Assuming that the op-amp can run on the RPi's 3.3V, this solution would lead to a follow-up question - is there an easy way to get -3.3V out of the RPi?

Comment: @bobthechemist I can't tell you but if there is a 5V supply that is accessible then using a simple linear voltage regulator can give you a local 3.3V supply. It may be that an analogue to digital converter on the RaPi might be 5V compatible? You'll still need to generate a negative voltage. What voltages do you have available to you?

Comment: The RPi as +3.3 and +5V.  I have no problem using an external power supply for the spectrophotometer part of this project.  My concern lies with the RPi; the documentation cautions the user against supplying more than 3.3V to the GPIO interface; therefore, I want to make sure the spectrophotometer output fits this criterion.

Comment: I'd use a rail-to rail op-amp powered from a small 3.3V linear voltage regulator then. Feed the regulator from 5V (to over 20V) but read the data sheet to check. There are plenty of linear voltage regulators that should be OK.